# jQuery Custom Second Custom Checkbox not Checking

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

So due to my dislike of normal checkboxes, I decided to use bootstrap v3's colored buttons as checkboxes. I made one, worked great(and worked with a POST request). Made a second, and it just doesn't work. The jQuery click function just isn't called at all. What do you guys think my issue is here?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmqwX/

```
<button id="checkbox" class="btn btn-default">foo</button>
<button id="checkbox" class="btn btn-default">not foo?</button>

$('#checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-success").attr("value", $(this).hasClass("btn-success"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same ID, use the classname instead.

```
$(".anyClass")
```

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about that.

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes, and then I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You should ***never!!*** have two elements with the same ID. Change your `checkbox` to a class:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="checkbox btn btn-default">foo</button>
<button class="checkbox btn btn-default">not foo?</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-success").attr("value", $(this).hasClass("btn-success"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right use class instead of ID and **Always ID's should be unique**.